# jquery-bootgrid: Get cell data in formatter?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just trying out bootgrid and it looks very nice, but there are a lot of holes in the documentation and it's difficult to figure out how to do some things.  Specifically, I am trying to simply format a date using moment.js in my bootgrid initialization.  I can see how you use the formatter to set the content of the cell, but your examples all just use the row.id and column.id.  I need to get the actual contents of the cell, the date, so I can format it and return it to the cell.  Is there a parameter that can be passed to the formatter function for the contents of the cell?

Also, I'm trying to figure out what the possible values are for 'data-type'? I only see 'numeric' in the examples, are there other types (perhaps a date type)?

Finally, I am manually appending the data to the bootgrid because my service calls are using the 'GET' method, rather than the 'POST' method.  It looks like bootgrid will ONLY use the 'POST' method to execute an ajax request, is that correct?  Is there a way to set it to another http method?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The documentation is currently in progress (sorry for that)! Regarding your question I recommend you to use a custom converter (data-type or data-converter). Take a look on the `default` settings [here](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/blob/master/src/public.js#L56-66).

Comment: From the docs: `Keep in mind when using  Moment.js to select one of the ISO-8601 datetime formats recommended  here when populating jQuery Bootgrid in order to avoid strange behaviour.` http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#converters

Comment: The `column.id` and `row.id` are the CELL DATA. In the examples, each of them had an ID column. `id` is the actual name of the column, the `data-column-id` value. You may also be able to use `row["id"]` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you need is **row[column.id]**

*Just try*

```
...
formatters: {
 myFormatter: function (column, row) {       
  var cellValue = row[column.id];
  // now edit the value
  return cellValue;
 }
}
```

at my case it works fine.